# navegacion router angular no lleva a mi otro componente

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo un input que al darle enter dispara un (ngSubmit) alli tomo al valor y se lo mando a mi ts pero no me funciona la navegacion.

Este es mi html

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="search( form.value )"  #form="ngForm" >

    <input class="form-control"
           type="text"
           name="name"
           required
           minlength="3"
           maxlength="10"
           [(ngModel)]="user">
    </a>
  </form>
```

Este es mi ts de ese componente

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  user: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  search(form) {

    let id: string = form
    console.log(id);
    this.router.navigate(['/detail',id]);

  }

}
```

en el console.log puedo ver que tengo el parametro pero la navegacion no me funciona.

este es mi routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'search', component:SearchComponent},
  {path:'detail/:id', component:DetailComponent},
  {path:'**', pathMatch:'full', redirectTo:'search'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

mi directorio de archivos es el siguiente:

```
app
  components
    search
    details
app.module.ts
app-routing.module.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

- Puedes verificar que si existe algun error en consola.
- revisa que tengas importado el componente `DetailComponent` en el modulo principal

Comment: no tengo errores en la consola, y si esta importado en el app.module

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude resolverlo en mi componente cambie la navegacion del router, lo comparto por si alguien le puede servir:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  user: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  search(form) {

    let id = form;
    this.router.navigate(['/details', id.user]).then(e =>{
      if (e){
        console.log("good work")
      }else{
        console.log("bad work")
      }
    });
  }

}
```